# DI Chaining with .NET 6 Generic Host

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I am trying to write a Windows service in .NET 6 (first attempt).  I have been able to set up the project just fine, but am running into issues when I attempt to chain dependencies.  So my constructors would be setup something like this (Worker added as HostedService, others as Singleton):

```
public class Settings
{
    public Settings(){}
}
public class Class1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Class1> _Logger;
    private readonly Settings _Settings;

    public Class1(ILogger<Class1> logger, Settings settings)
    {
        _Logger = logger;
        _Settings = settings;
    }
}
public class Class2
{
    private readonly ILogger<Class2> _Logger;
    private readonly Settings _Settings;

    public Class2(ILogger<Class2> logger, Settings settings)
    {
        _Logger = logger;
        _Settings = settings;
    }
}
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _Logger;
    private readonly Settings _Settings;
    private readonly Class1 _Class1;
    private readonly Class2 _Class2;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, Settings settings, Class1 class1, Class2 class2)
    {
        _Logger = logger;
        _Settings = settings;
        _Class1 = class1;
        _Class2 = class2;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _Logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>()
            .AddSingleton<Settings>()
            .AddSingleton<Class1>()
            .AddSingleton<Class2>()
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Now, when it tries to resolve the dependencies, I get the following error message:

> Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: DI.Worker': A suitable constructor for type 'DI.Class1' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

I went and tried to follow the steps listed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) and I get the same error.  I assume I am missing something but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: There's not enough details here. Show us more about `Class1`, and actual code since what you have shown here could never compile. Also show how you have added all these to DI.

Comment: Have you registered `Settings`, `Class1`, ... in the DI? Something like `serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Settings>(); serviceCollection.AddSingleton<Class1>(); ...` ?

Comment: I have added the full implementation

Answer (score 0):

In my actual application, I wasn't using interfaces for all of my services, instead adding them concrete.  As for the sample from the documentation, the classes were internal instead of public.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the order matters.

Try this:

```
     services.
        .AddSingleton<Settings>()
        .AddSingleton<Class1>()
        .AddSingleton<Class2>()
        .AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

If that is not it, then maybe Logging is not being setup.
It should be because you are using `CreateDefaultBuilder`, but that would be my next try.

If this does not solve it, can you provide the full `program.cs` and `startup.cs` files?